# Give example of metric space /normed linear space in which we have a proper subset which is clopen.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

In metric space the example of discrete metric space is very trivial  as in discrete msp every subset is clased as well as open,now iaaue becomes in case of normed linear space.whether such a normed linear space exists or not?I am unable to find such example please help me to solve this problem.Thanks in adavce.

Comment: Not possible in a  normed linear space. in $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$ (usual metric ) both these intervals are proper clopen subsets.

Comment: Is there any theorem regarding it?

Comment: Any normed linear is connected: any two points can be joined by a line segment.

Comment: I have not studied connected yet ...can you elaborate how connectedness relate this fact??

Comment: read first [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space) wiki page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a normed linear space and suppose that $A$ is a non-empty proper subset of $X$ which is open and cloded. Let $B:= X \setminus A$. Then $B$ is a non-empty proper subset of $X$ which is also open and closed. Furthermore we have

$(*) \quad X= A \cup B$.

Now take $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ and let $x(t):=a+t(b-a)$ for $t \in [0,1]$. Then $x(t) \in X$ for all $t \in [0,1]$.

It is your turn to get a contradiction to $(*)$.

Comment: Can you explain a little more.....I tried my best but didn't reach the destination....

Answer (score 0):

You need any disconnected metric space!  Also note that [normed linear spaces are connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531741/prove-that-a-real-normed-vector-space-is-connected), so we cannot find such a set in a normed linear spaces!

For example, In $\Bbb{Q}$ with the usual metric, the set $(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}) \cap \Bbb{Q}$ is clopen